# Using variable for tag in getElementsByTagName() for PHP and XML?

Tags: php, xml, getelementsbytagname, xmldom

See my PHP:

```
file = "routingConfig.xml";
global $doc;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( $file );

function traverseXML($ElTag, $attr = null, $arrayNum = 'all'){
    $tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName($ElTag);
    $arr = array();

    foreach($tag as $el){
        $arr[] = $el->getAttribute($attr);
    }
    if ($arrayNum == 'all'){
        return $arr;
    }else if(is_int($arrayNum)){
        return $arr[$arrayNum];
    }else{
        return "Invalid $arrayNum value: ". $arrayNum;
    }; 
}

echo traverseXML("Route", "type", 2);
```

XML is:

```
<Routes>
  <Route type="source"></Route>
  <Route></Route>
<Routes>
```

Error returned is:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object`

I'm not sure how to do this?

**EDIT:** Here is the actual code being used. I originally stripped it a little bit trying to make it easier to read, but I think my problem is related to using the function.

Comment: Are you certain that's all your code? I doubt it, because the error message would be impossible to achieve with the code shown. Please show your actual code.

Comment: In this particular case, I didn't think the remainder code was relevant, since the error was occurring on the line with the `$tag` variable. But I've added the remainder code.

Comment: Seems like perhaps the `$doc->load($file);` call is failing to load the file?

Comment: @Travesty3 that wouldn't turn `$doc` into a non-object though

Comment: Nope, that part works. I'm able to make it work if I just do `$doc->getElementsByTagName("Route");`, but if I utilize a variable it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jared: Something's not right there. It should make no difference whether you're using a variable or a direct string. Are you absolutely sure that this is the exact code you're using, or is there still something you're leaving out?

Comment: @Travesty3, I've modified it, this is the exact code being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `global $doc;` statement is *outside* the function, so the variable `$doc` is not defined *inside* the function.

This would fix it:

```
// ...
function traverseXML($ElTag, $attr = null, $arrayNum = 'all') {
  global $doc;
// ...
```

...*but*

**Global variables are bad news.** They usually indicate poor design.

Really you should pass `$doc` in as an argument, like this:

```
function traverseXML($doc, $ElTag, $attr = null, $arrayNum = 'all'){
    $tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName($ElTag);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($tag as $el){
        $arr[] = $el->getAttribute($attr);
    }
    if ($arrayNum == 'all'){
        return $arr;
    }else if(is_int($arrayNum)){
        return $arr[$arrayNum];
    }else{
        return "Invalid $arrayNum value: ". $arrayNum;
    }; 

}

$file = "routingConfig.xml";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( $file );

echo traverseXML($doc, "Route", "type", 2);
```

Although you might consider whether you need the function at all - if you don't use it anywhere else in you application, you might as well just do this:

```
$file = "routingConfig.xml";

$ElTag = "Route";
$attr = "type";
$arrayNum = 2;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( $file );

$tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName($ElTag);
$arr = array();
foreach($tag as $el){
    $arr[] = $el->getAttribute($attr);
}
if ($arrayNum == 'all'){
    echo $arr;
}else if(is_int($arrayNum)){
    echo $arr[$arrayNum];
}else{
    echo "Invalid $arrayNum value: ". $arrayNum;
};
```

Comment: I intend to expand the function later, and use it in multiple locations. Thanks for your help on this. I'm used to JS, where if you declare a variable in the parent or root of the document, all child functions have access to it.

Comment: I guess my next question is, by doing it your second method, everytime I call the function, I'm recreating a `DOMDocument()`. Is there a way around this without using Globals?

Comment: @Jared Sorry I'm not quote sure what you mean there? You can do `echo traverseXML($doc, "Route", "type", 2);` and then `echo traverseXML($doc, "SomeOtherTag", "otherAttr", 1);` immediately afterwards - passing `$dom` into the function doesn't mean you have to recreate it in order to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

The `$doc` variable is not defined inside your function. You have two options:

1. Pass `$doc` as one of the function arguments, which is preferred.
2. Write `global $doc;` at the top of your function ... devs usually try to avoid globals.